# Is there a reason the SQLAlchemy ORM tutorial puts angle brackets around its __repr__ values?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

The SQLAlchemy ORM tutorial uses this class:

```
>>> from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
>>> class User(Base):
...     __tablename__ = 'users'
...
...     id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
...     name = Column(String)
...     fullname = Column(String)
...     password = Column(String)
...
...     def __init__(self, name, fullname, password):
...         self.name = name
...         self.fullname = fullname
...         self.password = password
...
...     def __repr__(self):
...        return "<User('%s','%s', '%s')>" % (self.name, self.fullname, self.password)
```

Why would you go to all the trouble of having a string that will work nicely when `eval()`'d, only to break that functionality but surrounding it with angle brackets?

I realise that the `eval(repr(foo))` idiom is far from the only purpose of `__repr__`, but it it still seems odd how it seems to deliberately be disabled here. Is there some greater logic to this that I'm missing, or is it just some arbitrary decision?

Comment: This is just string representation of the object. If you want to change `repr` to use in `eval` then you can change it as per your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bear in mind that `eval` is not used too much; crafting strings for it (or checking if they really already work) is just unnecessary extra effort.
Putting the angle brackets in without second thought is much easier, and doesn't give people ideas about using `eval` (which is dangerous if you're not careful).

In other words, there was no deliberate decision to break `eval(repr(x))` here. It's just customary to put angle brackets around `__repr__` output.

Comment: Except that in this case, the string **is** nicely crafted for `eval(repr(x))`, *except* for the angle brackets, which, to me at least, makes it look like they were put there to stop people from thinking that was a smart thing to do.

Comment: No, it's **not** nicely crafted for `eval`. Try with someone named "O'Brian".

Comment: Ahhh, *that's* the kind of reasoning I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

the angle bracket convention is used by the Python interpreter itself, so this is more of a question for ...GVR ?

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     pass
... 
>>> f = Foo()
>>> print repr(f)
<__main__.Foo object at 0x1004ab290>
```

Comment: For the newbies out there: zzzeek (Mike Bayer) is the author of SQLAlchemy, and GVR (Guido van Rossum) made Python.

Comment: True that the default `__repr__` uses them, but it's also true that [the default repr is not helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2626364/665488). It just seemed odd to me that the SA tut uses `__repr__`s that happen to be perfectly executable, *except* for the angle brackets. That's really what prompted the question.

Comment: when the tutorial has some code with a `>>>`, then shows some results like `<User()>, <User()>`, at least the brackets make it clear this is string output, and not a new `User()` being entered in, though the format of the `>>>` should already make that clear...

Answer (score 0):

One argument for the angle brackets lies in semantics.  While `eval(repr(2)) is 2` all the time, `eval(repr(23094823589710L)) is not 23094823589710L`, and I do not believe that `eval(repr(myinstance)) is instance` will be true in general for instances of `mapper` classes.  Whether identity and equality are supported this way may even depend on the presence of unique constraints or other properties of the class.

Another issue is the availability of the class in the namespace.  If a particular class happens not to be in scope, `eval(repr(x))` will raise a `NameError`.

A more complicated example: I wrote my own library function (a metaclass) that accepts a table name as a string, dynamically creates a class using `type` as a constructor and `mapper` that already provides `__init__`, `__str__` and `__repr__` methods, and returns the new class.  All such classes have identical `__name__` attributes, so it is therefore impossible to support `eval(repr(x)) is x` or even `eval(repr(x)) == x` in my library function.  So I use angle brackets for `repr` in these classes.

My bet is, for these reasons and possibly others, the documentation uses angle brackets to avoid creating an expectation that `eval(repr(x)) is x` will always be supported.

Comment: While `eval(repr(2)) is 2` might always hold in the CPython implementation, it's not specified by the Python language, so relying on it is dangerous. Indeed, `eval(repr(300)) is not 300` even in CPython.